# How to copy the media file to web browser clipboard from finder or file explorer in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, clipboard

I need to copy files from finder and access the copied image / audio / video in the browser clipboard (chrome / firefox / safari).

I've tried to access using the clipboard API. As per official docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read it says partially supported.

```
const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read();
console.log(clipboardItems);
const blobOutput = await clipboardItems[0];
const copiedMedia = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobOutput);
console.log('Media pasted ', copiedMedia);
```

I have tried with onPaste event and got the copied files https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-paste-upload-poc-klqld

Is there any other way to access those files in browser (chrome / firefox / safari) clipboard ?